# Simplification of factorial

Tags: factorial

Can $\frac{(N_2-k)!}{(N_1-k)!}$ be expressed using $\Delta N = N_2-N_1$ as the only variable?

It stems from $\binom {N_2-k}{N_1-k}=\frac{(N_2-k)!}{(N_1-k)!(N_2-N_1)!}$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

For $N_1=1$, $N_2=2$ and $k=1$ your xpression gives
$$
\frac{(2-1)!}{(1-1)!}=\frac{1!}{0!}=\frac11=1
$$

For $N_1=3$, $N_2=4$ and $k=1$ it gives
$$
\frac{(4-1)!}{(3-1)!}=\frac{3!}{2!}=\frac62=3
$$

In both cases $\Delta N=N_2-N_1=1$.

Comment: Yes, that's a very simple way to show it, thanks! Can you see any way to simplify the $\binom {N_2-k}{N_1-k}$? It just feels like there should be one, but I probably shouldn't let it's truthvalue come down to feelings.